# JavascriptExecutor - Selenium - Scrolling in Bootstrap modal windows with long content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

How do I scroll through a modal window that is created using Bootstrap's modal class? Generally we use the JavascriptExecutor and use the window.scroll/scrollBy method. But when I tried the same when a modal is popped up with long content, the scroll is happening in the actual webpage which is not focused. How do I scroll through content in a modal popup that has long content?

Example - Modal popup here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content

Comment: Can you consider sharing your work with us? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/mastersmind/full/eWaQaQ/

For scrolling to a content we can use `scrollTop` check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/mastersmind/full/eWaQaQ/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to scroll the dialog box. It is a javascript.
document.getElementById('exampleModalLong').scroll(0,1950). We can use javascript executor in selenium.
I have checked it for the example site and it is working fine.